# Local storage remove.item

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have a todo app.I made it to jquery and localstorage.Codes are correct but ı can't delete tasks from localstorage

```
function appendTaskToList(val) {
    $('#list').append($("<li id='task-' + i >  <a href='#' class='done-btn'>Done</a>" +" " + val + " <a href='javascript:void(0)' class='cancel-btn'>Delete</a></li>").data("erdem", "12"));
}

if (localStorage['tasks']) {
    var tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage['tasks']);
}else {
    var tasks = [];
}

for(var i=0;i<tasks.length;i++) {
    appendTaskToList(tasks[i]);

}

var addTask = function(){
    var val = $('#name').val();
    tasks.push(val);
    localStorage["tasks"] = JSON.stringify(tasks);
    appendTaskToList(val);
    $('#name').val("").focus();
};

localStorage.username = $('#add-btn').click(addTask);
$('#name').keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        addTask();
    }
});

$(document).delegate('.done-btn', 'click', function() {
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('done');
    return false;
});

$(document).delegate('.cancel-btn', 'click', function() {
    $(this).parent('li').remove();
    localStorage.removeItem($(this).parent('li').remove());
});
```

please help me and sorry for my bad english

Comment: [`removeItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem) method expects a key name as a parameter. But you pass the result of jquery's `remove()` method which is jquery object.

Comment: how can i define a key ?

Comment: the same way as you use it when invoke [`setItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) method

Comment: you should update the value in localStorage 'Tasks' key, you shouldnt remove items. which means you should take the value in "tasks" key, find the item you want to remove and delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `removeItem()` method of the Local Storage, when passed a key name, will remove that key from the storage.

For the code you can extract the name of the task from the li and then use that to update the tasks array and then update the local Storage `tasks` value.

For your code:

```
//extract task name from the li element
var nameOfTask = $(this).parent('li').clone().children().remove().end().text().trim();
//find index in the task element
var index = tasks.indexOf(nameOfTask);

tasks.splice(index,1);
localStorage["tasks"] = JSON.stringify(tasks);
```

Please see this for ref: 'https://jsfiddle.net/bhtvt1c3/1/'

Comment: this code worked but it deletes reverse ı want delete the first task but this code deletes last task always deletes last child

Comment: @OğuzhanKaracan: Can u please elaborate the above comment?? As per the code we are getting the list item on which the delete button is clicked and then deleting that element from the array through its name.

Comment: ı click the first item in array but this code deleting the last item in array how can ı fix it ?

Comment: Updated the answer. Added a trim() function to remove all the whitespaces if present. Now it will never remove the last element again!! Sry for the inconvenience :-)